# How to do multiple operations on iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I'm new to programing on iOS, i need to build  app that will download some files from a web server, and while doing this, updating a status bar, but i don't want my app to freeze, so the user can still perform other operation on the app. Any idea ?.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. You should start by building a strong understanding as a foundation for your work. One way to begin is the read Apple's [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091). Also review relevant sample applications included in Xcode, and the appropriate documentation. Then you'll be able to start your work and ask focused detailed questions. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

iOS has a built-in asynchronous (i. e. non-blocking) HTTP client class.

Construct a `NSURLConnection` object. Provide the request parameters, provide a delegate, call [start]. The file will start downloading, but the app and the rest of the phone won't be frozen. Update your status bar all you want.

The delegate class methods would have to collect the incoming data and handle completion.

Answer (score 0):

Most common networking tasks (including image requests, JSON pulls, etc) can actually be achieved asynchronously very easily with the excellent [AFNetworking library](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

An example request:

```
-(void) startDownloadOfSomeFiles
{
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/a_file.zip"]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: request];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // Request was successful.
        NSString* path = ....
        operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // Network request failed. Bummer.
    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

As for updating a progress bar, you'll have to do that on the main thread, as such:

```
[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    aProgressBar.progress++; // or whatever
}];
```

That could be done within your request success block, for example.

All UI related stuff has to happen on the main thread in iOS. [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] allows you to add operations on to the queue. More on that in a sec. If you try to update UI elements from a background NSOperation, your app will most likely crash.

If you are interested in doing threading in general, the easiest way to use background threads is with your own NSOperationQueue (which is also how AFNetworking does it behind the scenes). You can create your own NSOperationQueue with the standard alloc/init, and you can set the following property on it:

```
NSOperationQueue* myOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
myOperationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1; //or 2, 3, whatever
```

This gives you the flexibility to use the *addOperation* method to enqueue tasks. You can either subclass *NSOperation*, or, for lighter tasks, you can just use

```
[myOperationQueue addWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"I'm running in a background thread!");
}];
```

NSOperationQueue will queue up the operations you put into it and execute them in order, on worker threads it manages, based on the maximum thread count you assigned it. If there are no threads waiting, it will start executing an operation as soon as you enqueue it; if there are threads waiting, it will be queued up and start as soon as a worker thread becomes free.

*[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]* follows the same guidelines as the above. What you're really doing is accessing the operation queue that iOS is using for your UI (which is why it's a really bad idea to add long running stuff on it - you'll freeze your app, since you're effectively running your code synchronously). You can't change the number of concurrent operations on the main queue, but you can enqueue UI-related tasks into it, as mentioned above.

Hope this gives you some insight into the fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

use multithreading. 
you can also use dispatch queues. there much easier than everything else ive seen.
if you have heard of objective c blocks, it uses that as basic c api.

```
dispatch_queue_t myCustomQueue;
myCustomQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyCustomQueue", NULL);

// put work here for separate thread
dispatch_async(myCustomQueue, ^{
    printf("Do some work here.\n");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      // do stuff in the main thread
    }
});
```

note that all UI Kit functions must be called in the main thread.
all background work in anyother queue.

good luck and heres the dev concurency guide too.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html`